# Iframe in a fancybox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm having a hard time implementing an Iframed video into a fancybox.

This is my code:

```
<a href="#movie-wrapper" class="showmovie fancybox">
 <div id="movie-wrapper">
   <iframe id="movie" width="300" height="169" src="<?=$this->getElement("contextPath");?>/movie/<?= $this->getElement("movieId"); ?>/iframe"></iframe>
 </div>
</a>
```

I put a div around the iframe because the video started bugging, but now, it only opens after clicking a couple of times and if it opens, the non-iframed video disappears.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this instead ?

```
<a href="<?=$this->getElement("contextPath");?>/movie/<?= $this->getElement("movieId"); ?>/iframe" class="showmovie fancybox">open video</a>
```

and the script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    width: "80%", // or whatever
    height: "80%"
});
```

I personally don't like inline iframes because you will be adding some overhead to your page load among other things.

On the other hand, my guess about your issue is that you are using fancybox v1.3.4. If so, there is a known issue when using inline iframes that you can read more about it here :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/1zIbmk31sgs

It also includes the workaround I proposed back in June 2011 in case you really want to stick to inline iframes with that version of fancybox.

BTW, if using inline content with fancybox v1.3.4 you have to be aware about this other bug and workaround https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM